# Why is map2() function doesn't find my column name?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm using the `map2()` function to select elements from a list column with vectors using purr in tidyverse. While it work with a mock example with generic names:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = list(1:3, 4:6),
  y = c(2, 3)
) 

#This works:
df %>% mutate(z = unlist(map2(x, y, ~ .x[.y])))
```

But when I give the same column a name purr doesn't find the column:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(vol = x)

#This doesn't work
df %>% mutate(z = unlist(map2(vol, y, ~ .vol[.y])))
```

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `z = unlist(map2(vol, y, ~.vol[.y]))`.
> Caused by error in `.f()`:
> ! object '.vol' not found

Comment: Change `.vol` to `.x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the formula notation with `map2()`, the default parameters are called `.x` and `.y`, whatever the name of the argument passed to the function. So in this case replace `.vol` with `.x`:

```r
df  |> 
    mutate(z = unlist(map2(vol, y, ~ .x[.y])))
```

Note the `map2` [documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) states that `.f` must be:

> A function, specified in one of the following ways:
>
> - A named function.
> - An anonymous function, e.g. (x, y) x + y or function(x, y) x + y.
> - A formula, e.g. ~ .x + .y. **You must use .x to refer to the current element of x and .y to refer to the current element of y.**

(Emphasis mine.)

The docs also state that the formula notation is *[o]nly recommended if you require backward compatibility with older versions of R.* To use a named parameter instead, e.g. `vol`, you can use an anonymous function:

```r
df |>
    mutate(z = unlist(map2(
        vol, y, \(vol, y) vol[y]
    )))
#   x             y vol           z
#   <list>    <dbl> <list>    <int>
# 1 <int [3]>     2 <int [3]>     2
# 2 <int [3]>     3 <int [3]>     6
```